# How to hide the turtle arrow while keeping the turtle shape?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

With my turtle in black i create a shape (the white rectangle) and not a line ! Then i move the white shape at the bottom of the screen to create a paddle that must move from left to right. I have to keep the shape but remove the black arrow. How to do ?

[image]

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")  # what i want to keep to move it from left to right
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=5)
        self.color("white")
        self.goto(x=0, y=-260)

        # I create my turtle, now I can move the shape, the white rectangle.
```

And then I move my turtle shape from left to right.
In general I leave the background black and we don't see the turtle (the shape rather), but here I am melting is lighter, so we see the black arrow in the center of the screen.

Comment: Your approach (minimal reproducible code along with the output ) to make the paddle or the game would be helpful to identify the issue

Comment: What's likely here is that you've mixed the *functional* and *object-oriented* APIs of turtle and the arrow you're seeing is the *default* turtle which you don't need.  This error would be easy to spot if you provided your code.

Comment: Sorry for that, i just posted the code.

Comment: that is not a [mre] (which is what you should provide, that is neither a small part of your code nor your entire code (in most cases), it is code that is as minimal as possible, it can reproduce the issue and can be simply copy-pasted and run)

Comment: Ok thanks, I have modified the code for better understanding.

Comment: after penup, move the turtle to an off-screen coordinate

Comment: This is exactly what I have to do to move the shape from left to right, But the arrow remains in the center of the screen, the proof in the image. I descended the shape with goto () but the arrow remains.

Answer (score 1):

`hideturtle()` using to make a circle (for example) without show the turtle arrow

You can see this source:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-hideturtle-function-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in the example you show me the turtle makes a line and then disappears, what I want to do is place my turtle in a place on the screen, then move it from right to left, so my shape must remain but if I hide the turtle the shape also disappears. I want to keep the shape but not the arrow, it's a problem for me, since I don't want it.

Comment: You were right, that was it, while preparing my class, there was another turtle below, that's why I didn't understand. Thanks to you.